# Where is Scala 2.10.3 hosted?

Tags: scala

I can find Scala 2.10.3 on http://www.scala-lang.org/download/.  Is there no yum or apt-get repository?

Comment: After clicking on a version on [this page](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html), you'll have the installers available at the bottom of the new page. Or you can just go [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/).

Comment: Which Ubuntu/Fedora version are you using...?

Comment: Official Scala people have decided not to maintain OS-specific repositories for Scala releases. So there are no official ( read as guaranteed maintained ) repositories for Scala. Some OS-maintainers and communities maintain their own repositories for Scala, but those are not officially maintained. So the best and most official solution is to either go with `TypeSafe Activator` or download a deb/rpm and install it. @LMeyer has already provided the official download location.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I has already answered my own question by providing the same link that @LMeyer gave.  The information I didn't know what the official policy was of Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official Scala apt-get/yum repo.  Where I started this questions is where I ended up: http://www.scala-lang.org/download/.